# PHP mvc routes dont operating

Tags: php, url-routing

I use PHP with MVC for my system, actually with XAMPP because the project is in development process. But on routes without frameworks, the URL "http://localhost/home", for example, return error 404, object not found. I use .htaccess with RewriteEngine On.

.htaccess ->

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Sistema/ccbsys/auth/src/index.php  [L]
```

index.php ->

```
<?php
    include('Routes/routes.php');

    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if (isset($routes[$url])) {
        list($controllerName, $action) = explode('@', $routes[$url]);
        $controllerFile = 'Controller/' . $controllerName . '.php';

        if (file_exists($controllerFile)) {
            require $controllerFile;

            $controller = new $controllerName();
            $controller->$action();

            $controller->render();
        } else {
            echo "Error controller file";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Route not found";
        var_dump ($routes);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<?php include './core/head.php' ?>
<body id="page-top">
    <div id="wrapper">
    
        <?php include './core/sidebar.php' ?>
    
        <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
            <div id="content">
                <?php include './core/topBar.php' ?>
                <?php include './core/footer.php' ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php include './core/modaLogout.php' ?>
    <?php include './core/script.php' ?>    
</body>
</html>
```

routes.php ->

```
<?php
    $routes = [
        '/home' => 'DashboardController@render',
    ];
    return $routes;
?>
```

DashboardController.php ->

```
<?php
    class DashboardController {
        public function render() {
            return ("TESTE");
        }
    }
?>
```

The XAMPP is configured and the port is operating!

httpd.conf ->

```
<Directory /var/www/htdocs/Sistema>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I try config the XAMPP and .htaccess, but i dont have idea if it is operating with success. The routes are the problem!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would change the `index.php`:

The part before `<!DOCTYPE html>` can be moved to a new file `./core/main.php`.

Then in this `index.php` you have a nice layout:

```php
<?php 
    include './core/topBar.php';
    include './core/main.php';
    include './core/footer.php';
?>
```

You can remove `$controller->render();`.

I guess it's a test for `$controller->$action();`.

This action returns a string message but needs an `echo;`

```php
echo $controller->$action();
```

Maybe add some `exit;` to debug each file.

```php
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    var_dump ($routes);
    exit;
    ...
} else {
    echo "file $controllerFile not found."; //instead echo "Error controller file";
    exit;
}
```